# How to list disk space usages of all containers on an OpenVZ server?

Tags: openvz, disk-space-utilization, diskmanagement, containers

I have an OpenVZ server with 46 containers. How do I get a list of all the containers with their corresponding disk usage?

Answer (score 3):

Use `vzlist` with the `diskspace` option, for instance:

```
vzlist -a -o ctid,hostname,diskspace -s diskspace
```

Comment: How do i get it in GB?